# I want a html link and <form> element appearing in the same Line

Tags: html, forms, line

This is my html code:

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/bookManagementProject/asset/images/mainLogo.gif"><a>

<br> <FONT SIZE=3 FACE="Arial"><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 
<a href = "http://127.0.0.1/home.html" <b>Home<a> |
<a href = "http://127.0.0.1/login.do" <b>Login</a> | <form method="get" action= http://flyingame.gamehost.org:8080/search.do> Search: <input type="text" name=searchTermFromBanner> <input type="submit" value=Search></FONT></br>
```

The problem is, the `<form>` element is not appearing in the same line as the "Home" and "Login"

by the way, this is a banner html code

Comment: I would start by brushing up on your HTML, and maybe looking into CSS.

www.w3schools.com

Comment: To all the people who are criticizing my html know how, I'm a Java Programmer by heart, since I am currently learning Searvlets and JSP, I had to delve into html a bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to put the link inside the form:

```
<form method="get" action="http://flyingame.gamehost.org:8080/search.do">
    <font size="3" face="Arial">
        <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1/home.html" <b>Home</b><a> 
        |
        <a href = "http://127.0.0.1/login.do" <b>Login</a> 
        |
        Search: 
        <input type="text" name="searchTermFromBanner" /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </font>
</form>
```

You should probably clean up your HTML a bit (`<font>` has been replaced by CSS some years now). Quote your attributes too, and watch for missing semicolons on your entities.

Answer (score 2):

you SHOULDN'T do this, but you can fix it by just assigning display:inline to the form

```
<form method="get"  style="display:inline;"  action="http://flyingame.gamehost.org:8080/search.do"> Search: <input type="text" name="searchTermFromBanner"> </form>
```

it should be in a separate css file and not in a  "style" tag.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS:

```
form#the-form-id {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: this is the best answer for me :)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this, but the simplest is just to expand the form to include the other links thus:

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/bookManagementProject/asset/images/mainLogo.gif">
<br> <form method="get" action= http://flyingame.gamehost.org:8080/search.do><FONT SIZE="3" FACE="Arial"><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 
<a href = "http://127.0.0.1/home.html" <b>Home</b><a> |
<a href = "http://127.0.0.1/login.do" <b>Login</b></a> | 
 Search: <input type="text" name="searchTermFromBanner"> <input type="submit" value="Search"></FONT></form>
```

More generally you are closing `<br>` tags which you can't and not closing  tags which you should.  Also you have a completely erroneous `<a>` tag on the first line.

If we're getting really picky, your use of the font tag has not been best practice for some time.  You should be looking at CSS.

Answer (score 0):

As Gareth Simpson and Greg said, the easiest way is to wrap the links in the  tag, but, SERIOUSLY, you shouldn't be using the  tag, also, the fact that the browsers display the  without the alt attribute and unclosed, doesn't mean that you should be doing it.

I agree with idrumgood, it would be great if you can check www.w3schools.com, for your own good.

Cheers